# upload csv to solr core using cURL on Windows

Tags: curl, solr

I've been looking around the web for good documentation for using solr on Windows, but I just can't find much out there.  I'm using solr v5.4.1.

Following the tutorials [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/apache-solr-tutorial-beginners/), I've installed solr and built a new core, installed cURL, and run what seems to be a curl command with no errors, but the data is not uploading to my server.  I have modified `schema.xml` to include all of the column-header names that are in my CSV.

Here's the command I'm running to upload the data in test.csv to my core.

```
D:\solr\solr-5.4.1\bin>curl http://localhost:8983/solr/ti/update?commit=true --data-binary @d:\test.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

and the response I get upon hitting enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1071</int></lst>
</response>
```

When I go back to the Solr Admin panel, I see that 0 documents exist in my core, but I'm not getting any error message from curl, or from the response indicating I'm doing something wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out in cURL, but I did figure out how to use the `post.jar` file that is bundled with solr to do it.

`#post a csv to a core named "abc" using the post.jar file in example\exampledocs`

I am running this command from `D:\solr\solr-5.4.1\` where my solr installation lies.

```
java -Dc=abc -Dtype=text/csv -Dfiletypes=text/csv -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar d:\test\test.csv
```

**Where:**

`-Dc=` is the name of the core that already exists in solr

`=Dtype=` and `Dfiletypes=` is the type of file you're uploading

`-jar example\exampledocs\post.jar` needs to be a reference to the location where your `post.jar` file exists.`

`D:\test\test.csv` is the location of the csv file you're uploading.

Also note, prior to this working, you need to modify the `schema.xml` file in solr to add the column headers in your CSV file to the solr core.

Hope this helps SOMEONE! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late. But for those who want to import their data to a solr core from CSV file using cURL. Here is the cURL command for it.

```
curl 'http://<Solr-server>/solr/<solr-core>/update?commit=true' --data-binary @<path-where-your-csv-fil-located> -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. No documents visible after posting the documents using curl. The following worked for me.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/fpi_auto/update?stream.body=%3Ccommit/%3E
```

Basically, it commits the documents to the solr.

Comment: "stream" no longer works with Solr, was deemed insecure.  There's an alt syntax, but don't have it handy.